# Transport error: org.apache.http.HttpException: Scheme 'https' not registered

Tags: 2013, transport, https

I have a new HTTPS deployer endpoint, and I can connect to it just fine in the browser on the CM server (although there is a non-trusted certificate issue) however when I try to publish I get an error. The following is in the transport log. Any ideas?

> 2014-07-03 10:16:37,051 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to
>   execute File retrieval on destination:
>   https://somesite.sdl.com:8285/HTTPUpload.aspx
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: null  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
>   ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
>   ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
>   ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]   at
>   com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(HTTPSTransportConnector.java:247)
>   ~[cd_transport.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(TransportPoolConnector.java:80)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:54)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:36)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.(DestinationController.java:108)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerFactory.getDestinationController(DestinationControllerFactory.java:41)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionProcessor.java:134)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.(TransactionProcessor.java:48)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:253)
>   [cd_transport.jar:na] Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: Scheme
>   'https' not registered.   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.java:115)
>   ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:723)
>   ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:358)
>   ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
>   ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]   ... 11 common frames omitted

Comment: Can you put your transport service logging to DEBUG, retry and post the log here? Did you add the SSL certificate to JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts ?

Comment: Could an error like this be cause by https://somesite.sdl.com:8285 serving an invalid (or self signed) SSL certificate?

Comment: It is indeed a certificate issue... Wouldn't it be nice if Java just for once had an error message that made sense ;o)

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the transport service JRE cannot find the SSL certificate. It needs to be imported as described in the [SDL Tridion Docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-60D158FC-CDBE-48B8-A011-8699740549B1) [login required]

Run the following from command prompt (in jre/bin):

```
keytool -import -file mycertificate.cer -keystore c:\path\to\jre\lib\security\CACERTS
```

Then update cd_transport_conf:

```
<Sender Type="HTTPS" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector">
    <KeyStore Path="c:\path\to\jre\lib\security\CACERTS" Secret="my-keystore-password" />
</Sender>
```

Thanks for the hints Raimond and Jan!

Comment: FYI: the default keystore password is 'changeit' :)